# AQGridView (UIScrollView) cells disappear and reappear on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, aqgridview

There is an awkward blinking that is very visible when scrolling `AQGridView`.

I have looked at this link => [Calling reloadData causes all cells to blink](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/issues/110).

I am calling `reloadData` while loading cells for the **first time**, but my guess is this is happening internally when cells are being reused.

Any clues about methods to implement? Will `lazy loading` help here?

**EDIT:**

And oh, this happens when I scroll, which might be the cause

`Visible cell list is missing some items!
Got 6 missing indices`, any clues?

This is my issue on github => https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/issues/194